# Issue with neo4j query with collect and delete clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j. For my requirement, I need to get the list of ids(collect) and delete the nodes as well in the same query.

In the below query when i just return the ids, i get the right result i.e; 2 ids

```
START n=node:galleryid(galleryid='f0666ac5-9f61-4431-80b1-c9719ef8c1f9') 
MATCH n-[rels*1..]->p 
WITH n, rels, p, collect(p.photouniqueid) as photoids 
RETURN photoids;
```

Result as expected and got it: `["3dcd792b-9eed-4a74-826a-6801c9f2b707"] ["e5c91a60-41cf-4afb-8aa6-49a4af00dd38"]`

But when i try to append the delete clause to the query i get only one of the ids.

```
START n=node:galleryid(galleryid='f0666ac5-9f61-4431-80b1-c9719ef8c1f9') 
MATCH n-[rels*1..]->p WITH n, rels, p, collect(p.photouniqueid) as photosid 
FOREACH(rel IN rels: DELETE rel) 
DELETE p 
WITH n, photosid 
MATCH n<-[r]-() 
DELETE n, r 
RETURN photosid;

Result - ["3dcd792b-9eed-4a74-826a-6801c9f2b707"]
==> 1 row
==> Nodes deleted: 3
==> Relationships deleted: 3
```

Can somebody please suggest what is the issue with 2nd query? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You probably delete an relationship in between that is needed for the next match. Try to aggregate the results you need beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
START n=node:galleryid(galleryid='f0666ac5-9f61-4431-80b1-c9719ef8c1f9') 
MATCH n-[rels*1..]->p 
WITH n, collect(path as paths) collect(p.photouniqueid) as photosid 
FOREACH(p IN paths: 
  FOREACH(r in rels(p) :  DELETE rel)
  FOREACH(x in tail(nodes(p)) : DELETE x)
)
WITH n, photosid
MATCH n<-[r]-() 
DELETE n, r 
RETURN photosid;
```

Won't return anything if 2nd match doesn't find any paths